# How to add scientific 'references' with plotly, matplotlib ,seaborn?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, seaborn

I´m working on some plots for my Thesis. I want to add some 'reference' to every plot. I realy dont know the english term for that, thats why I cannot just google the documentations, but i mean something like this:

[image]

or:
[image]

I dont need an answer with code, but maybe someone may share a  link of documentation for creating such plots. (I would prefer plotly).

Kind Regards

Comment: In Plotly you can add some text to the plot as an annotation, see the documentation: https://plotly.com/python/text-and-annotations/#text-annotations.

Comment: In matplotlib, it is always good to start by screening the tutorials and examples. There is an [entire section on text, labels, and annotations.](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/index.html#text-labels-and-annotations). See also "fancyarrow".

Answer (score 3):

In case of matplotlib, you can use [`matplotlib.pyplot.text`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.text.html), something like the following:

```
...
txt = 'Some caption'
fig.text(.5, .05, txt, ha='center')
```

You might need to play with the arguments to position it where you need exactly.